# Ora can run on worker thread in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to run [`ora`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ora) in nodejs worker?

I have a simple example I use to run ora in another worker. but the problem is freezes after the first output.

app.ts:

```
import { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } from 'worker_threads';
import path from 'path';

const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, './worker'));
```

worker.ts:

```
import ora from 'ora';

console.log('in worker!!!');
ora('starting...').start();
```

Do I miss something here? or ora can't run on Worker?

[image]